# Derivative of conjugate map

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

The Wikipedia page for the adjoint representation has the following:

> If $G$ is an immersed Lie subgroup of the general linear group $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ (called immersely linear Lie group), then the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ consists of matrices and the exponential map is the matrix exponential $\exp(X) = e^X$ for matrices $X$ with small operator norms.
> Thus, for $g$ in $G$ and small $X$ in $\mathfrak{g}$, taking the derivative of $\Psi_g( \exp(tX) ) = g e^{t X} g^{-1}$ at $t = 0$, one gets
> $$
>   \mathrm{Ad}_g(X) = g X g^{-1}
> $$
> where on the right we have the products of matrices.
> If $G \subset \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a closed subgroup (that is, $G$ is a matrix Lie group), then this formula is valid for all $g$ in $G$ and all $X$ in $\mathfrak{g}$.
>
> ([Original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfm15.png))

What I don’t understand is how taking the derivative of $\Psi_g$ with respect to $t$ gives $\mathrm{Ad}_g$. I understand that $\mathrm{Ad}_g$ is the pushforward of $\Psi_g$, but don’t understand how the pushforward is related to the $t$ derivative in this case.

Comment: In your title, should "conjugate" be replaced by "adjoint"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concede that it is a lot of circonlocutions in order to deliver a quite trivial result, but the idea is as follows : $g\in G$ lives in the Lie group, whereas $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ is an element of the associated Lie algebra. The great result of Lie theory constitutes the correspondence between a Lie group and its algebra through the exponential map, such that $A=e^{tX}\in G$ and $X = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0} \in \mathfrak{g}$, i.e. $G\xrightarrow[]{\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}t}\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}\xrightarrow[]{\exp}G$ in other words.

In your case, the conjugation map $\Psi_g$ is defined for the Lie group, but you want to "extend" it to its algebra, that is why $X$ is brought into the Lie group by exponentiation first, then $\Psi_g$ is applied to $e^{tX}\in G$ and, finally, differentiation permits to switch back to the Lie algebra. One has thus :
$$
\mathrm{Ad}_g(X) := \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0} \Psi_g(e^{tX}) = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0} ge^{tX}g^{-1} = \left.ge^{tX}Xg^{-1}\right|_{t=0} = gXg^{-1}
$$

Comment: I see, so I think what I was missing was that you could express X as $X = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t = 0}e^{tX}$. But how are you able to take the t derivative outside of the function arguements in the second equality? And wouldn't that be $\psi_g$ not $Ad_g$?

Comment: @KevinGuo You're right, I was careless, the symbol $\textrm{Ad}_g$ should be reserved for congugation in the algebra and $\Psi_g$ in the corresponding group, as written in your source. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @KevinGuo I'm not sure to understand your other question (about the second equality). Could you explicit it ?

Comment: The definition of the push forward of a map $F: M \rightarrow N$ of $v \in T_xM$ is $$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}F(c(t)) \in T_{F(x)}N$$ where $c$ is a smooth curve such that $c(0) = x$ and $c'(0)= v$. Observe that if $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, then $c(t) = e^{tX}$ satisfies $c(0) = I$ and $c'(0) = X$. Therefore, $$\mathrm{Ad}_g(X) = (\Psi_g)_*X = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\Psi_g(e^{tX}).$$ From here, @Abezhiko's answer takes over.

Comment: Observe that this allows you to define $\mathrm{Ad}_g: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ for an abstract Lie group (that is not a matrix group), even though $gXg^{-1}$ is ill-defined.

Comment: @Deane 's answer was the missing part I needed! For me another way I like to think about it is to use the definition of a tangent vector as a velocity to the curve. ie

Comment: $$ Ad_g X f := X(f\circ \psi_g :=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(f\circ Ad_g \circ c)) $$, where c(t) is the curve $c(t) = \exp{tX}$. Then $$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} (f\circ Ad_g \circ c))  = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} f(ge^{tX}g^{-1}) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(ge^{tX}g^{-1})^i_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i_j} f$$ And thus the thrid equality in @Abezhiko 's answer can be identified with the coefficients of the last equality above